# Unable to connect to spark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, docker-compose, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Running the Python code does not connect to Spark and does not create a database in Cassandra either. I have confirmed the services are up on docker and accessible from the PC. I placed the .jar files in the pyspark jar folder of my .env.

**I have tried:**

- Google and ChaGTP.
- changed cassandra host name from `localhost` to docker hostname `cassandra`.
- added: `.master("spark://spark-master:7077")` \ to `s_con`.
- Confirmed that `spark_conn = create_spark_connection()` is not completing. `if spark_conn is not None:` never starts.

[The github repository](https://github.com/gregorywmorris/cwy_realtime_streaming)

**Error:**

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.

ERROR:root:Couldn't create the spark session due to exception An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
```

**spark_stream.py:**

```
import logging
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def create_keyspace(session):
    session.execute("""
        CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS spark_streams
        WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'};
    """)

    print("Keyspace created successfully!")


def create_table(session):
    session.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spark_streams.created_users (
        id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
        first_name TEXT,
        last_name TEXT,
        gender TEXT,
        address TEXT,
        post_code TEXT,
        email TEXT,
        username TEXT,
        registered_date TEXT,
        phone TEXT,
        picture TEXT);
    """)

    print("Table created successfully!")


def insert_data(session, **kwargs):
    print("inserting data...")

    user_id = kwargs.get('id')
    first_name = kwargs.get('first_name')
    last_name = kwargs.get('last_name')
    gender = kwargs.get('gender')
    address = kwargs.get('address')
    postcode = kwargs.get('post_code')
    email = kwargs.get('email')
    username = kwargs.get('username')
    dob = kwargs.get('dob')
    registered_date = kwargs.get('registered_date')
    phone = kwargs.get('phone')
    picture = kwargs.get('picture')

    try:
        session.execute("""
            INSERT INTO spark_streams.created_users(id, first_name, last_name, gender, address, 
                post_code, email, username, dob, registered_date, phone, picture)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        """, (user_id, first_name, last_name, gender, address,
              postcode, email, username, dob, registered_date, phone, picture))
        logging.info(f"Data inserted for {first_name} {last_name}")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'could not insert data due to {e}')


def create_spark_connection():
    s_conn = None

    try:
        s_conn = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName('SparkDataStreaming') \
            .config('spark.jars.packages', "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.13:3.4.1,"
                                           "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.4.1") \
            .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost') \
            .getOrCreate()

        s_conn.sparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO")
        logging.info("Spark connection created successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Couldn't create the spark session due to exception {e}")

    return s_conn


def connect_to_kafka(spark_conn):
    spark_df = None
    try:
        spark_df = spark_conn.readStream \
            .format('kafka') \
            .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'localhost:9092') \
            .option('subscribe', 'users_created') \
            .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest') \
            .load()
        logging.info("kafka dataframe created successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(f"kafka dataframe could not be created because: {e}")

    return spark_df


def create_cassandra_connection():
    try:
        # connecting to the cassandra cluster
        cluster = Cluster(['localhost'])

        return cluster.connect()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Could not create cassandra connection due to {e}")
        return None


def create_selection_df_from_kafka(spark_df):
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("id", StringType(), False),
        StructField("first_name", StringType(), False),
        StructField("last_name", StringType(), False),
        StructField("gender", StringType(), False),
        StructField("address", StringType(), False),
        StructField("post_code", StringType(), False),
        StructField("email", StringType(), False),
        StructField("username", StringType(), False),
        StructField("registered_date", StringType(), False),
        StructField("phone", StringType(), False),
        StructField("picture", StringType(), False)
    ])

    sel = spark_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
        .select(from_json(col('value'), schema).alias('data')).select("data.*")
    print(sel)

    return sel


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create spark connection
    spark_conn = create_spark_connection()

    if spark_conn is not None:
        # connect to kafka with spark connection
        spark_df = connect_to_kafka(spark_conn)
        selection_df = create_selection_df_from_kafka(spark_df)
        session = create_cassandra_connection()

        if session is not None:
            create_keyspace(session)
            create_table(session)

            logging.info("Streaming is being started...")

            streaming_query = (selection_df.writeStream.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                               .option('checkpointLocation', '/tmp/checkpoint')
                               .option('keyspace', 'spark_streams')
                               .option('table', 'created_users')
                               .start())

            streaming_query.awaitTermination()
```

**docker_compose:**

```
version: '3'

services:

  zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.0
      container_name: zookeeper
      hostname: zookeeper
      ports:
        - "2181:2181"
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      healthcheck:
        test: ['CMD', 'bash', '-c', "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 2181"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 5
      networks:
        - confluent

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.4.0
    container_name: broker
    hostname: broker
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://spark-master:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "bash", "-c", 'nc -z localhost 9092' ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.4.0
    container_name: schema-registry
    hostname: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8081/" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.4.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
      schema-registry:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      CONFLIENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      PORT: 9021
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9021/health" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  webserver:
    image: apache/airflow:2.6.0-python3.9
    container_name: af-webserver
    hostname: af-webserver
    command: webserver
    entrypoint: ['/opt/airflow/script/entrypoint.sh']
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Sequential
      - AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow
      - AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_SECRET_KEY=this_is_a_very_secured_key
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./script/entrypoint.sh:/opt/airflow/script/entrypoint.sh
      - ./requirements.txt:/opt/airflow/requirements.txt
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD-SHELL', "[ -f /opt/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - confluent
  
  scheduler:
    image: apache/airflow:2.6.0-python3.9
    container_name: af-scheduler
    hostname: af-scheduler
    depends_on:
      webserver:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./script/entrypoint.sh:/opt/airflow/script/entrypoint.sh
      - ./requirements.txt:/opt/airflow/requirements.txt
    env_file:
      - airflow.env
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Sequential
    command: bash -c "pip install -r ./requirements.txt && airflow db upgrade && airflow scheduler"
    networks:
      - confluent

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.0
    container_name: af-postgres
    hostname: af-postgres
    env_file:
      - postgres.env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
    networks:
      - confluent

  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    container_name: spark-master
    hostname: spark-master
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - confluent
      
  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    container_name: spark-worker
    hostname: spark-worker
    ports:
      - "8082:8081"
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://172.27.0.7:8082"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - confluent

  cassandra_db:
    image: cassandra:latest
    container_name: cassandra
    hostname: cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    env_file:
      - cassandra.env
    environment:
      - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=512M
      - HEAP_NEWSIZE=100M
    volumes:
      - ./:/home
    networks:
      - confluent

networks:
  confluent:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `spark.cassandra.connection.host` to `localhost` because for the Spark application it will be its own container, while you have Cassandra running in another container.  You need to use Cassandra container name instead.

Comment: After running with the container name/hostname (they are the same) 'cassandra', I am getting: cassandra@cqlsh> describe spark_streams.created_users;
'spark_streams' not found in keyspaces

Comment: Did you change the name in `create_cassandra_connection` as well?

Comment: Yes, it now states 'cluster = Cluster(['cassandra'])'. Still no table. Spark errors remain.